# Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $request

Tags: php, slim

I have a strange error here. I am building a REST API with Slim framework.

```
 $app->post('/createuser', function(Request $request, Response $request){

    if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('email', 'password', 'name', 'school'), $response)){
        $request_data = $request->getParseBody();

        $email = $request_data['email'];
        $password = $request_data['password'];
        $name = $request_data['name'];
        $school = $request_data['school']; ...
```

The Error:

```
Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $request in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/RestAPIwithSLIM/public/index.php on line 17
```

I DO NOT know which paramater is missing on this post function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have `Request $request, Response $request` - both have the same name!

Answer (score 9):

You have defined two parameters with the same name, ideally you'd change the second parameter to `$response`.

`$app->post('/createuser', function(Request $request, Response $response) {`